# What data structure in R is suitable to store models?

Tags: r

Say I'm training models:

lm.1, lm.2, ... , lm.100

I would like to refer back to these later in my code for various purposes: say to inspect coefficients, run test data against them, etc.

What data structure should I use to store them in?

A list is what I've been using but lists for some reason seem a bit unwieldy of all the data structures in R

Comment: thanks: @ZheyuanLi anything other than a list come to mind?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi sorry about that -- thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly a list.

A complete `lm object` is a list; the only thing in R that can hold a list is just a list. We have no other option.

In some cases, even if the return of a model is just a vector, we can not guarantee the resulting vectors are of equal length for all models we try, so we still have to use a list.